# Unable to send push notification with ACS REST API after login

Tags: javascript, api, rest, titanium, appcelerator

i would like to create a html/javascript form on my website. With the form i woud like to send push notifications too Android and iOS devices.

The login http request works fine:

```
httpRequest.open('POST','https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/login.json?key=xxxAPKEYxxx&login=xxxEMAILxxx&password=xxxPASSWORDxxx');
    httpRequest.send();     
    httpRequest.onload = function(){             
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var sessionID = data.meta.session_id;
sendPush();
}
```

the response: {"meta":{"code":200,"status":"ok","method_name":"loginUser".... So the login is success. But then when i call the sendPush function, i get a response error: the response error: 
 "status":"fail",
    "code":400,
    "message":"Failed to authenticate user".

```
function sendPush(){  
    httpRequest.open('POST','https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key=xxxAPPKEYxxx&channel=xxxCHANNELxxx&payload=test');
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onload = function()
 {
   console.log(this.responseText);
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sendPush(){  
    var BASEURL = 'https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/'
    httpRequest.open('POST', BASEURL + 'push_notification/notify.json?key=APPKE');
    httpRequest.send({
       channel : "xxxCHANNELxxx",
       payload : "test"
    });
    httpRequest.onload = function() {
       console.log(this.responseText);
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron Saunders, thanks for your reply! Do you also know which protocol ACS use for calling the Apple Notification service?